# Prove dot product identity $u\cdot v = \tfrac14(|u \cdot v|^2 − |u − v|^2).$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

$$u\cdot v = \dfrac14\left(|u \cdot  v|^2 − |u − v|^2\right).$$

So far I've only gotten the RHS to $\tfrac14((u \cdot v)(u \cdot v) − |u|^2 + 2(u \cdot v) - |v|^2)$

Only way I see this working is if $(u \cdot v)(u \cdot v)$ is equal to $|u + v|^2$ but that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: It is not $|u\cdot v|^2$, it is $|u + v|^2$. Simple counterexample to the formula you've written:
Take $v = 0$, then it becomes

$u \cdot 0 = \dfrac{1}{4}\left(|u\cdot 0|^2 - |u - 0|^2\right)$
$\Rightarrow$
$0 = \dfrac{-|u|^2}{4}$

which obviously doesn't hold for any non-zero vector $u$.

Comment: It is $\;u+v\;$ in the RHS in the first equality

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was doing a past paper and the question definitely says  |u⋅v|^2 which much be an error then.

Answer (score 3):

Directly, and assuming the dot product is over a **real** vector space:

$$\frac14\left(||u+v||^2-||u-v||^2\right)=\frac14\left(\color{red}{||u||^2}+\color{green}{||v||^2}+2u\cdot v-\color{red}{||u||^2}-\color{green}{||v||^2}+2u\cdot v\right)$$

and we're done

Answer (score 1):

See [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) and [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) for your (corrected) formula's point, geometric interpretation, usage and generalizations.